# Star Trek novel in which the Enterprise-A is sold as surplus and refitted with Klingon technology

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, novel

I'm trying to recall a licensed *Star Trek* novel that I encountered in the early 2000's decade.

The gist of the story is that after the NCC-1701-A is decommissioned after the end of *The Undiscovered Country*, it is stripped of its weapons and sold onto the surplus market, where it is purchased by an independent (but Federation-friendly) world or faction as a sort of Air Force One for its leader. I specifically remember a scene in which the *Enterprise* is in a spacedock being refit with Klingon-made disruptor cannons (as these are apparently much easier for a non-aligned world to purchase on the open market), and there is a discussion on how ironic this was considering the particular history of this ship.

Later in the story, the *Enterprise* finds itself at the center of a civil war or other conflict being waged by its new owners, and ends up getting thoroughly pulverized. I believe it is stated that the ship is either completely destroyed at the end or can no longer be salvaged at all.

Can anyone identify the novel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is William Shatner's *The Ashes of Eden*. Per [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Ashes_of_Eden) (the *Star Trek* wiki), "the Enterprise-A was sold by Starfleet to the defense forces of the planet Chal, who appointed the now-retired James Kirk as its commander. The vessel was later destroyed in the corona of Chal's sun during a battle with Klingon battle cruisers."

Memory Beta (the noncanon-inclusive *Star Trek* wiki) confirms that the *Enterprise* was refit with Klingon technology: "When Chal's population takes control of the vessel, they retrofit the ship with Klingon disruptors and sensors, replacing the previous classified Starfleet technology stripped out of the vessel."